# Microservices: Cancelling Asynchronous Jobs

Tags: asynchronous, cloud, microservices, message-queue

**Problem**

Consider a social networking website supporting the following actions:

- **MediaUploadService**: You can upload media files (images and videos) either a single file or multiple files.
- **TaggingService**: Once the files are uploaded, all the persons identified in the files are tagged automatically.
- **NotificationService**: Once the files are tagged, all the persons get notified.

The following requirements must be satisfied:

- The user can cancel the upload at any time which means the uploading should also be stopped. It also means that the tagging and notification services should not even be triggered for such requests.
- All the services should be able to retry the failed jobs.
- All the services communicate through messaging infrastructure.
- The services must be scalable and available.

**My Take**

We can have a **global task queue** and the upload service can listen for new jobs. The request can be represented as:

```json
{
   "request_id":"abcd-defg-pqrs",
   "total_files": 2,
   "files":[
      {
         "id":"bcde-efgh-qrst",
         "name":"cat.jpg",
         "type":"image"
      },
      {
         "id":"cdef-fghi-rstu",
         "name":"kitty.mp4",
         "type":"video"
      }
   ]
}
```

The request is broken into the single file upload request and is pushed to the **upload-request** message queues:

```json
{
   "request_id":"abcd-defg-pqrs",
   "total_files": 2,
   "file":{
      "id":"bcde-efgh-qrst",
      "name":"cat.jpg",
      "type":"image"
   }
}
```

Each request is picked and processed as a background job and the response is sent to the **upload-response** aggregator which keeps count of the total files uploaded:

```json
{
   "request_id":"abcd-defg-pqrs",
   "total_files": 2,
   "uploaded_files": 1,
   "file":[
      "bcde-efgh-qrst"
   ]
}
```

Once all the files are uploaded the final response is sent to the **tagging-request** message queues:

```json
{
   "request_id":"abcd-defg-pqrs",
   "total_files": 2,
   "files":[
      "bcde-efgh-qrst",
      "cdef-fghi-rstu"
   ]
}
```

When the tagging service is done with the job, it sends the request to the **notification-request** message queues. Finally, once we have all the tasks completed, the user can be notified about it using **global-response** message queues.

**Concerns**

- For retry failed jobs, we can have other low-priority queues for each of the services. What if we want to give the same priority and process with retries in a real quick time as well?
- Processing the jobs respecting the dependencies on the services, i.e., `upload` → `tag` → `notify` is taken care of using the messaging queues. Is there any better way to achieve the same?
- How can we immediately stop files uploading (assuming file upload is still in progress by the time we are making a cancellation request)? For the uploaded files, we can simply go ahead and delete the files.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [temporal.io](https://www.temporal.io/) which provides a much better way to model such use cases. It is essentially a workflow engine that uses code without any intermediate representation. Cancellation and compensations are supported out of the box.